# '_UnreadVariable' object has no attribute 'run' when trying to run keras optimizer

Tags: python, optimization, keras, tensorflow2.0, attributeerror

I am trying to run the example code in the [tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer) page. I get the following error when I try to run it.

`AttributeError: '_UnreadVariable' object has no attribute 'run'`

Following is the code that I am trying to run.

```
import tensorflow as tf

var1 = tf.Variable(0.0)
var2 = tf.Variable(0.0)


opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)
loss = lambda: 3 * var1 * var1 + 2 * var2 * var2
opt_op = opt.minimize(loss, var_list=[var1, var2])
opt_op.run()
```

Comment: I even  tried this in a google colab envrionment. Still the same error.

Comment: I found a workaround for this problem. I was running this with Eager execution enable ( without graphs ) . I disabled eager execution and ran within a session ( default graph ). It worked without any error.

Comment: can you add the details of the compile errors that you got on Google colabs?

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-4-40b08155f3c8> in <module>()
----> 1 opt_op.run()

AttributeError: '_UnreadVariable' object has no attribute 'run'

Comment: I ran ur code and fot the same error, see my explanation on the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

var1 = tf.Variable(0.0)
var2 = tf.Variable(0.0)
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)
loss = lambda: 3 * var1 * var1 + 2 * var2 * var2
#loss_fn = lambda: f(var1, var2)
# init vals
print("Initial values:",some_fn(var1,var2).numpy())

# this is applicable only on graph mode
#opt_op = opt.minimize(loss, var_list=[var1, var2])
#opt_op.run()
# however, just call this in eager mode
opt.minimize(loss, var_list=[var1, var2])

opt.variables()
```

Colab notebook: [tensorflow_optimizer_stackoverflow_q1.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kgo2p6uOEYMWu3k5exmvxeu22LqGn7GE)

Run:
[image]

Reference: [tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer](https://s0www0tensorflow0org.icopy.site/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer?hl=ID)

One good example that will clear you understanding: [tensorflow optimizer v2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py)

---

**Update**:

**When you should use Eager execution in TensorFlow?**

> It is imperative to use eager execution in TF when you want to
>   evaluate operations immediately, without building graphs. TF
>   operations return concrete values instead of constructing a
>   computational graph to to be used and run later.  Also it makes it
>   easy to ignore all jargons and get easily started with TensorFlow and
>   debug models.

Comment: I checked and this works fine. This needs to be run with Eager execution enabled. Is there a disadvantage to running earger execution enabled ?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve, for example you don't want a computational graph stored for later execution/or input to other steps down the line then it makes sense to use eager execution, it is a exec immediate

Comment: Added some updates to the answer to make it clear. Can I ask what are trying to achieve? or u r simply getting started with TF and Optmizers?

Comment: I am actually getting started and learning the basics. Thanks.

Comment: Ok let me know if you find the answer useful and whether it solves your issue.

Comment: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f7e465097467> in <module>()
      7 #loss_fn = lambda: f(var1, var2)
      8 # init vals
----> 9 print("Initial values:",some_fn(var1,var2).numpy())
     10 
     11 # this is applicable only on graph mode

NameError: name 'some_fn' is not defined`